# VRPTW Optaplanner using Partitioned Search

Tags: java, optaplanner

I've implemented the partitioned search in the VRP problem, and it works very well. Then I tried to implement the VRPTW problem. After the init process the previousStandstill's arrivalTime sometimes null and caused an error in `ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.java`  specifically when `.getDepartureTime()` is called.

```
Long departureTime = previousStandstill == null ? null
                : (previousStandstill instanceof TimeWindowedCustomer)
                        ? ((TimeWindowedCustomer) previousStandstill).getDepartureTime()
                        : ((TimeWindowedDepot) ((Vehicle) previousStandstill).getDepot()).getReadyTime();
```

```
15:34:47.101 [PartThread-2] DEBUG             CH step (197), time spent (8548), score (-2init/0hard/-8026964soft), selected move count (247), picked move (TimeWindowedCustomer-350 {null -> TimeWindowedCustomer-222}).
15:34:47.106 [PartThread-1] INFO          Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (8552), best score (0hard/-8128814soft), score calculation speed (9281/sec), step total (200).
15:34:47.146 [PartThread-2] DEBUG             CH step (198), time spent (8593), score (-1init/0hard/-8124288soft), selected move count (248), picked move (TimeWindowedCustomer-164 {null -> Vehicle-51}).
15:34:47.200 [PartThread-2] DEBUG             CH step (199), time spent (8647), score (0hard/-8138330soft), selected move count (249), picked move (TimeWindowedCustomer-72 {null -> TimeWindowedCustomer-270}).
15:34:47.203 [PartThread-2] INFO          Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (8650), best score (0hard/-8138330soft), score calculation speed (9196/sec), step total (200).
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
previousStandstill arrivalTime is null
```

Does anyone has encountered the same problem as me? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow variables should be in sync with the genuine vars for an input/output model.

For example if C = A + 5 and A is 10 then C should be 15. If A is 200 then C should be 205. If A is null then C should be null.

Try turning on enviromnentMode FULL_ASSERT, which validates input data for this requirement.

Comment: Also you might very much like this issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1316

Comment: Thank you for your help. After I traced the errors, it seems like some vehicle chains failed to initiate the arrival time. So, in that chain, all of the customers don't have arrival time. Then I created the calculation algorithm to calculate the arrival time of that customer. What do you think about that? Is that okay?